# Display Tag Issue

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

I have collections of data to display so how to display those data using `<display>` tag in JSP file.

I have just written

```
<display:table name="user" pagesize="10" export="true" sort="list">
    <display:column property="firstName" title="First Namee"
                    sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
    <display:column property="lastName" title="Last Name"
                    sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
    <display:column property="Email" title="email" sortable="true"
                    headerClass="sortable" />
</display:table>
```

It is working but data is not displayed

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you are doing in your controller. Is your `user` attribute really holding any data?

Comment: Where your data is stored ?

Comment: it is stored in mysql database and i am fetching those data in controller class

Comment: HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();

      ArrayList arrayList=new ArrayList();
      for ( User users : userRepository.findAll()) {
             arrayList.add(users.getFirstName());
             arrayList.add(users.getLastName());
             arrayList.add(users.getEmail());
         }
         httpSession.setAttribute("user", arrayList);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/newPage.jsp");

dispatcher.forward(request,response);

Comment: this is my controller class from where i m dispatching request to jsp page where my <display tag> is

Comment: but when executing, 404 error is occured and not displaying my jsp page.

Comment: yes user attribute is class where my getter and setter methods for firstname , last name and email were there

Comment: This issue is resolved